# What are the meanings of abbreviations used by the users?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Haven't had much luck searching for 'OP' and 'OT' terms in the search box, what does these abbreviations used by users in StackOverflow mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I certainly can't recite all the abbreviations off the top of my head, but I can answer one:

#### OP = Original Poster (the asker)

<s>In all honesty, I've never heard of OT. Maybe if you give an example use I could take a guess at it, but I don't know it as-is.</s>

I've just been enlightened:

#### OT = Off Topic

Also, here's some more abbreviations you might find:

### Close Reasons

- NARQ: Not A Real Question
- NC: Not Constructive
- TL: Too Localized
- OT: Off Topic

### Flag Reasons

- NAA: Not An Answer
- VLQ: Very Low Quality

Comment: **OT** = Off Topic

Comment: @p.s.w.g Ah. Makes sense now.